# Accessing object property using a variable

Tags: android, kotlin

I'd like to access a property of a class dynamically by its name. I know its possible using Reflection. But i was wonder if Kotlin has something similar to Javascript:

```
Object['propertyname'] = "new value"
```

Or like in python:

```
setattr(Object, 'propertyname', "new value")
```

### Update:

So I guess this is the current way to go, thank you Syed Ahmed Jamil:

```
person.javaClass
     .getMethod("setName", String::class.java)
     .invoke(person, "new value")
```

Comment: I guess kotlin does support Java style reflection as mentioned in the docs here : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/member-references-and-reflection.html#java-style-reflection